# EJS inside of Style

Tags: html, css, node.js, ejs

I want to manipulate width depending on information from the server by inputting ejs tags there but I can't figure out how. Is there a way to do something similar?

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped infoTxt" style="width:40%">energy</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using ejs like this:

use <%= widthfromserver %> in place of 40%

Answer (score 0):

I would create a seperate script tag and adjust the styling that way.

```
document.getElementByClassname("progress-bar").style.width = width + '%';
```

Alternatively you can use the following syntax

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped infoTxt" style="width:<%= width %>%">energy</div>
</div>
```